# Play! 2.1 pass request to another Scala controller

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

Since APIs like `routeAndCall` (Java-specific) have been deprecated in Play! 2.1, how do I pass the request to another controller in Scala?

Something like:

```
def this = Action { implicit request =>
  if(request.body) routeAndCall(controller.App.methodWithPostBody)
  else Ok("hello")
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routeAndCall` method's deprecation annotatation hints to use the `route` method instead:

```
@deprecated("Use route instead.", "2.1.0")
```

Comment: thanks for posting it. i forgot to add my answer after i browsed the source code ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case? Can you use client side redirect? This method is deprecated for reason: if the application is performing redirection on server side, then client side will not aware of the redirection.

Comment: did to include a controller that's included with a plugin. we're checking to ensure that the request is made on the correct domain, and if it is then we pass the request to the specific plugin controller. looks like the method was simply refactored because of Play 2.1's new dynamic routing